# ViewModel observe is running multiple times for a single hit to API

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android, android-livedata, observers

I have a Chart in fragment and a switch. On switch selection the API needs to be hit again with a new value and chart needs to be updated, the API code is as shown:

```
   private fun hitSecondChartApi(country: String, category: String, market: String, weightKpi: String) {

        userModel.getResponseShareSecondChartData(country, category, market, weightKpi)
        Log.e(TAG, "Inside hitsecondchartapi: "+ country+":"+category+":"+market+":"+weightKpi)
        userModel.responseSecondChartData.observe(this,
                Observer {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Second chart data: " + it.toString())
                    Utils.debugger("FRAG ", "$it")
                    secondChartData = it!!
                    if (it.size > 0) {
                        splitSecondParentList(it!!)
                    } else
                        Utils.showLongToast(requireActivity(), "No Data for Distribution")
//                    userModel.responseSecondChartData.removeObservers(this)
                })
    }
```

Now the problem here is the "**Observer is running multiple times when i turn ON/OFF switch and it is also providing me the values of the previous API request first and then of the current API**" E.g The response which i had received in the Switch On state is still again received when i will turn off the switch and vice versa. Its like a stack.

E.g: **Switch Turned On**:    Response off-> Response off-> Response On-> Response On-> Response On

**Switch Turned Off**:  Response On-> Response On-> Response off-> Response off-> Response off

For a workaround i tried to remove the observer which you can also see in the above code in the commented line but it has one flaw because it will only run once and i may or maynot get the current API response from it.

One thing i can do is to filter out the response but i need a proper fix for this issue that i should receive only the current API response at it should run only one time as i won't be able to filter out for the other API's.

So please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: Try with `SingleEvent` https://proandroiddev.com/livedata-with-single-events-2395dea972a8

Comment: @LiemVo There is no need to remove this observer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time `hitSecondChartApi()` is called, a new observer is attached to `LiveData` and these duplicated observers are causing the unexpected result. Solutions like `SingleEvent` or `SingleLiveData` can technically hide this effect but it will not remove the root cause.

Correct solution is to call `responseSecondChartData` only once at the beginning of the `Fragment`/`Activity` initialization. For example:

```
fun onActivityCreated(...) {
    userModel.responseSecondChartData.observe(this,
            Observer {
                Log.e(TAG, "Second chart data: " + it.toString())
                Utils.debugger("FRAG ", "$it")
                secondChartData = it!!
                if (it.size > 0) {
                    splitSecondParentList(it!!)
                } else
                    Utils.showLongToast(requireActivity(), "No Data for Distribution")
            })
}

private fun hitSecondChartApi(country: String, category: String, market: String, weightKpi: String) {
    userModel.getResponseShareSecondChartData(country, category, market, weightKpi)
}
```

There is no need to remove observer in above code because its creating only one observer.

Comment: Thank you for clearing out this concept behind the observer.